# Getting the count of isograms in a python list

Tags: python, function

I am trying to build a function that gets the count of isograms in a python list without importing a library/package. I can accomplish this with a singular string, but having difficulty doing so in list format.

The List would be like so:

```
l =['please', 'find', 'isograms', 'if', 'you', 'can']
```

The function should return the number 4, since 4 of the strings do not have repeating characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you accomplished with a singular string?

Comment: *"I can accomplish this with a singular string"* - Then all you need to do is put it in a loop and count.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following:

```
[len({}.fromkeys(x)) == len(x) for x in l].count(True)
```

or

```
[len(set(x)) == len(x) for x in l].count(True)
```

---

```
>>> l =['please', 'find', 'isograms', 'if', 'you', 'can']
>>> [len({}.fromkeys(x)) == len(x) for x in l].count(True)
4
>>> [len(set(x)) == len(x) for x in l].count(True)
4
```

This works by converting each string to a dictionary, which eliminates duplicates, and checks if the length is equal to the original length. Then it counts the number of `True` values in the list.

Comment: Or you can just use `set` . Still +1

Answer (score 0):

You state in the question that you're able to determine if a single string is an isogram or not. I'll assume that means you already have a function `is_isogram(string)` that returns `True` if `string` is an isogram, or `False` otherwise.

If so, try this:

```
count = sum(is_isogram(s) for s in l)
```

The generator expression inside the `sum` function basically just computes the value of `is_isogram` for each item in `l` (a `True` or `False` value). The `sum` function then implicitly converts these Boolean values to their integer equivalents (i.e. `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`), and computes the sum. Since there should be one `1` for each isogram in the list, the sum should exactly equal the number of isograms.

If instead of a function you have some expression for testing for isograms (e.g. `len(set(string)) == len(string)`), then simply substitute in place of the `is_isogram(string)` in the above code, e.g.:

```
count = sum((len(set(s)) == len(s)) for s in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    len( [word for word in l if len(word) == len(set(word))] )
```

(where the part `len(word) == len(set(word))` means to include only words without repeating character, as in the `set(word)` are not included duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

This will work try this one it will pass all the hidden test for codewars

```
def is_isogram(string):
    string = string.lower()
    for char in string:
        if string.count(char) > 1:
            return False
    return True
```